# Sorting 2 row file.csv using UNIX

Tags: unix

I need some help sorting this this .csv
The sort needs to be accouring to the first row with y and y related so they have to sort along and so on...

```
y, d, a, w, c,.......
y, d, a, w, c,.......
```

**output**

```
a, c ,d ,w ,y
a, c ,d ,w ,y
```

Thanks

Comment: can't we write a small java program that can read this and sort as you want. If so I can write one?

Comment: i need it using unix shell script :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input is pretty straight forward comma separated list of strings this list hacky use of `tr` and `sort` could do the job for you.

```
$ echo " y, d, a, w, c" | tr , "\n" | sort | tr "\n" , | sed 's@,$@\n@'
 a, c, d, w, y
```

For a more generic-solution try using `GNU awk` as following:-

```
$ cat script.awk
#!/bin/gawk

BEGIN {
    FS=","                          # Setting input-field-separator to ','
    OFS=","                         # Setting output-field-separator to ','
}

{
    split($0, words)                # Split the strings and store it in array
    asort(words)                    # Using gawk's inherent sort function 'asort' sort the words alphabetically
    for (i in words) $i=words[i]    # Store the words back in the array and printing the same
    print
}
```

And a sample input file

```
$ cat input.csv
pineapple,blueberries,strawberries
pencil,crayon,chalk,marker
bus,car,train,motorcycle,bicycle,skateboard
```

Run the script using `gawk` as

```
$ gawk -f script.awk input.csv
blueberries,pineapple,strawberries
chalk,crayon,marker,pencil
bicycle,bus,car,motorcycle,skateboard,train
```

Comment: @Johnny: Use the `gawk` solution, in the recent update

Comment: I really loved the hacky first!

Comment: @SergeBallesta: Being a long-time user you can acknowledge it through a nice "upvote" :) unless you meant it ironically

Comment: @Inian was about to do it (and I've done now), but I was preparing a way based on your working for multi line inputs. Feel free to include it in your answer if you like it and ping me so I can remove mine.

Comment: @SergeBallesta: Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way based on Inian's original answer - credits should remain to him...

```
while true
do read line
if [ "x${line}" == "x" ]
then break
else
echo $line | tr , "\n" | sort | tr "\n" ,
echo
fi
done
```

Simply use it that way: `line_sort.sh < orig_file > sorted_file`

---

Disclaimer: this works only for very simple csv. CSV produced by spreadsheets can be far more complex because CSV can support newlines and commas inside fields. If I wanted a robust solution I would use a true language and a CSV library. Python comes with an excellent CSV module included...

Comment: nice approach with `<  >` re-direction :)